# Continuously read self overwritten outputs and parsing the lines

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection, stdout

Sometimes a program outputs content that is self overwritten by default.
For example, the output of `dd if=(something) of=(something) status=progress` has the following output model:

```
56670413312 bytes (57 GB, 53 GiB) copied, 1938 s, 29.2 MB/s
```

and the values keep changing without printing new lines (thus, a self overwritten output).

I've replicated this behavior with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# POSIX!

limit=50
i=1; while [ $i -le $limit ]; do
  echo -n "testing $i\r"
  i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

Therefore, at each second, the following line is replaced with the current number, without printing (appending) other lines:

```
testing <number>
```

The problem is: how could I continuously watch this kind of output for parsing and treatment of information?

For example, I wanted to take the output of dd and parse it in a way that I get a percentage of conclusion.. Something like:

```
# This is the output model:
# 56670413312 bytes (57 GB, 53 GiB) copied, 1938 s, 29.2 MB/s

# Parsing the output
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 status=progress | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d '(' -f 2 | awk '{print $1"GB concluded of 10000GB"}'
```

I would expect, at least, to get an append of printed lines showing:

```
1GB concluded of 10000GB
2GB concluded of 10000GB
...
```

But instead, nothing happens, the output is completely ignored by the pipe.

To reproduce the output of dd in those circumstances, you can use the above script as a model:

```
#!/bin/sh
limit=50
i=1; while [ $i -le $limit ]; do
  echo -n "56670413312 bytes ($i GB, 53 GiB) copied, 1938 s, 29.2 MB/s\r"
  i=$(($i + 1))
  sleep 1
done
```

How can I continuously get that output to parse the way I want it?
(Preferably in POSIX)

Comment: `dd` writes that information to stderr. Pipe stderr to awk.

Comment: Thank you for the awnser @muru, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to apply to the example script I showed last on the post.  
The example prints to stdout but I still unable to  pipe and parse the output.  
But is good to know about dd writing to stderr, thank you.

Comment: The other thing is that you need to split lines on `\r`, not `\n` (the default for awk and most line-based tools). Otherwise those tools will wait until a `\n` newline appears in the input. Try with `awk -v RS="\r"` or something.

Comment: Your script isn't overwriting the output lines, it's continuous appending to the output but placing the cursor back at the start of the line every time so it **looks like** it's overwriting the output. Try writing the output to a file and you'll see it grow instead of remain 1 line.

Comment: Also, `awk '{print $3}' | cut -d '(' -f 2 | awk '{print $1"GB concluded of 10000GB"}'` can be written as `awk '{sub(/\(/,"",$3); print $3"GB concluded of 10000GB"}'` or even just set the FS to include `(`: `awk -F'[( ]+' '{print $3"GB concluded of 10000GB"}'`